# Find condition of a type of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $(X, d)$ and $(Y, \rho)$ be compact metric space. If  continuous
map $f:(X, d)\rightarrow (Y, \rho)$ is Lipschitz map then 
for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for every
$n\in\mathbb{N}$ when $\sum_{i=1}^{n}d(x_i, y_i)<\delta$ we have
$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\rho(f(x_i), f(y_i))<\epsilon$.

In my research I need to find conditions to imply that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for every
$n\in\mathbb{N}$ when $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}d(x_i, y_i)}{n}<\delta$ we have
$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\rho(f(x_i), f(y_i))}{n}<\epsilon$.

Can you help me to know it.

Comment: Your two conditions seem be be equivalent, by multiplying both sides by $n$. Anyway, I would perhaps call this "absolute continuity"? Although I have only seen it defined for real-valued functions defined on an interval of $\mathbb R$ before.

Comment: @Math1000, But equivalence of two conditions do not clear for me. Yes, First condition is known as absolute continuous.

Comment: Take $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon/n$ and $\delta'=\delta/n$ and multiply both sides by $n$. You have the original condition.

Comment: @Math1000, Thanks. But for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$......